# Populate UITableView from NSArray/NSDictionary containing strings in plist

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, nsarray, nsdictionary

I currently have a tab bar view controller with a navigation view controller within each of my two tabs. Each navigation controller has a table view controller. I want to populate both tables with the same information, but in a different sorting order. All of my information is currently contained in a plist - one big array which contains 30 dictionaries which have 3 or 4 strings each. How do I get my tables to populate each cell according to the string for each for key "A" in each dictionary? I've done all the work in Interface Builder regarding associations and class references. Thanks so much!

Comment: Have you tried looking at examples of how to set up a tableView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you look at some of the examples in [the documentation for `UITableView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html). The main things you will need to do are to set up a data source that must adopt the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol and, if you have a delegate, that must adopt the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol. Then you can load the data into the table using the method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` are different protocols - you only need to implement some of the DataSource methods for very basic table views. If you want to handle a more customised table view, or you need to handle events (such as the user selecting a cell), you'll also need to implement some of the Delegate methods. The method you've mentioned is a DataSource method, not a Delegate method.

Comment: @Nick: You are correct. I edited my answer to be more accurate and precise.

Comment: I've tried tons of examples and watched countless videos, but I'm just rather inexperienced and frustrated. I'll try implementing your code, thanks!